# Rounded WebView on OSX with Cordova?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cordova, webview

I'm creating a Mac OSX application with [Cordova-osx](http://cordova.apache.org). I've tried to implement all solutions I've seen about having rounded corners for my app but none of them work. Last resource will be removing the shadow and creating the corners with CSS but I don't really like that approach.

So, [this is the file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx/blob/master/CordovaFramework/CordovaFramework/Classes/CDVViewController.m) in charge of creating the webview and loading it. And this was my approach:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    _commandDelegate = [[CDVCommandDelegateImpl alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    self.webViewDelegate.viewController = self;

    NSURL* appURL = nil;
    NSString* loadErr = nil;

    if ([self.startPage rangeOfString:@"://"].location != NSNotFound) {
        appURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.startPage];
    } else if ([self.wwwFolderName rangeOfString:@"://"].location != NSNotFound) {
        appURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", self.wwwFolderName, self.startPage]];
    } else {
        NSString* startFilePath = [self.commandDelegate pathForResource:self.startPage];
        if (startFilePath == nil) {
            loadErr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR: Start Page at '%@/%@' was not found.", self.wwwFolderName, self.startPage];
            NSLog(@"%@", loadErr);
            self.loadFromString = YES;
            appURL = nil;
        } else {
            appURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:startFilePath];
        }
    }

    if (!loadErr) {
        NSURLRequest* appReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:appURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
        self.webView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        self.webView.layer.opaque = NO;

        [[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:appReq];

    } else {
        NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body> %@ </body></html>", loadErr];
        [[self.webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    }

    for (NSString* pluginName in self.startupPluginNames) {
        [self getCommandInstance:pluginName];
    }

    // initialize items based on settings

    BOOL enableWebGL = [[self.settings objectForKey:@"EnableWebGL"] boolValue];
    WebPreferences* prefs = [self.webView preferences];

    // Note that this preference may not be Mac App Store safe
    if (enableWebGL && [prefs respondsToSelector:@selector(setWebGLEnabled:)]) {
        [prefs performSelector:@selector(setWebGLEnabled:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:enableWebGL]];
    }
}
```

Which basically is adding this:

```
self.webView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.webView.layer.opaque = NO;
```

This is the code I use to show the panel:

```
- (void) showPanel
{

    NSPoint mouseLocation = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

    NSEnumerator *screenEnumerator = [[NSScreen screens] objectEnumerator];
    NSScreen *screen;
    while ((screen = [screenEnumerator nextObject]) && !NSMouseInRect(mouseLocation, screen.frame, NO))
        ;

    NSRect statusFrame = [[self.statusItem valueForKey:@"window"] frame];
    NSRect winFrame = [self.window frame];
    NSRect screenFrame = [screen frame];

    NSPoint p = NSMakePoint(statusFrame.origin.x, screenFrame.size.height + screenFrame.origin.y - 32);


    if ((p.x + winFrame.size.width) > (screenFrame.origin.x + screenFrame.size.width)) {
        p.x = screenFrame.origin.x + screenFrame.size.width - winFrame.size.width - 30;
    }

    [self.window setFrameTopLeftPoint:p];
    [self.window setIsVisible:YES];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

But doesn't seem to be showing any rounded corners in the frame. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi can you please explain in your question what results you do get instead of "doesn't seem to be working "

Comment: I thought it was clear: I'm not seeing any rounded corners in the frame

Comment: It was not. I did not now what you where seeing in the view or any of the other things that could be wrong with it. When results do not work as expected you can get all manner of results. Stating what you are actually seeing, not seeing and any errors helps us help you to figure out what may be happening. The more detail the better.  For example. The webView appears as normal but without the rounded corners. There are no errors reported. And the webViews behaviours when scrolling etc are normal.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna try to move this code to viewDidLoad and add the self.webView.layer.masksToBounds = YES; after the self.webView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

Comment: @RobertoFerraz what's this code exactly? The `awakeFromNib` or the other one? `maskToBounds` doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: move all the code you wrote on awakefromnib to viewdidload.. then add the mastoBounds after the cornerRadius.. by the way, try bigger radius too, just to make sure that you will really see the round corner, then you put a size you want.

Comment: The `awakeFromNib` code is Cordova's. Not sure is good to move that? I've already tried to put something like 100 and doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

I still can't make suitable view because of white corners, but I made WebView's corners rounded. I wrote this just in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method:

```
self.webView.wantsLayer = YES;
self.webView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;
self.webView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[self.webView.mainFrame.frameView setAllowsScrolling:NO];
```

[image]

and as you can see rounding is works, but there also white places in corners, and I don't know how to deal with them

Comment: Try this: ``[self.webView setDrawsBackground:NO];``